# Warning on dependencies when create a new standard .NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

I have installed VS 2017 and I am sure all features related to.Net Framework, Core, C#, and ASP.NET are installed with others.

All I do is create a new project (.net standard class library) then the dependencies section is showing the warning (yellow triangle) sign. When I click on the dependencies visual studio freezes and close. If I try to work with any library I get the same error

> cannot resolve symbol

Any ideas please?

[image]

When I try to build the solution, I get the following error

[image]

**EDIT**

*I have also checked NuGet Package manager and found that the available source looks like below*

[image]

Comment: It seems VS fail to restore the dependence, if you follow Tools->options->Nuget Package Manager->is there any available source for Package Sources, if not, please try add with "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

Comment: Yes, It is there, I have Edit the question with another screenshot

Comment: If you run dotnet restore in Package Manager window, will you receive any error?

Comment: Well, half of the problem is fixed thanks to you :), now the project builds successfully but still have the yellow warning and if I clicked on Dependencies the VS hangs and restart

Comment: I assume it is related with VS, I suggest you try install the latest update for VS, and have you install .net core sdk https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows?

Comment: I did so, my version is 15.5.4 :(

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `.csproj` file of your new .NET Standard project?

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Comment: I've found that sometimes the icons in the Solution Explorer don't always update after some actions (I'm looking at you Git).  This might also be happening after your package restore.  Try restoring packages, either explicitly, or by a normal build, saving everything, then closing and restarting Visual Studio to see if the icon persists.  If the project can actually build, I find it hard to believe that the missing reference is actually missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, What I am going to say will sound CRAZY, but it is a fact and known issue and really hard to be found.

The problem is in the **project path**, the path for the project I have created contained a special character c:/users/Hussein Khalil(XXX)/PROJECT_NAME

when I created the project on a simple path c:/test/... everything is worked fine.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and it was not related with special characters in project path.

I executed "clean solution" and then "build solution" and it restored the dependency successfully. It solved the issue.